# Why the big jump in CVE-2017 numbering?

Tags: cve

Can anyone explain, why the numbering from [this years CVE entries](https://github.com/CVEProject/cvelist/tree/master/2017) jumped from CVE-2017-15xxx to CVE-2017-1000xxx?

What about entries with the numbering sequence CVE-2017-16xxx, CVE-2017-17xxx, and so on?

Why are ~984 000 entries not numbered sequentially?
Reading the [official documentation](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/identifiers/syntaxchange.html) gives me no idea about the answer to this question.

Comment: This might have to do with namespaces being reserved for handlers of responsible disclosure other than mitre. By allotting each some space, the sequence is broken.

Comment: I also noticed this today when I tumbled upon https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-1000101. Given this number it feels like @SmokeDispenser is right.

Comment: CNAs are allowed to reserve blocks of CVE IDs to use them later.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because this missing block was assigned to a CVE Numbering Authorities (CNA): https://cve.mitre.org/cve/cna.html. As soon as a CNA have a vulnerability affecting one of their own products, then those missing CVE will be assigned.

In the CVE details page, you can check which CNA assigned a specific CVE, i.e: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-8811 (Debian did it)

Answer (score 3):

CVE IDs are assigned by CVE Numbering Authorities (CNA).

The CVE program uses a federated CNA structure.

[image: CNA structure]

When a CNA wants to assign a CVE ID, it must request a CVE ID block from its parent, which will mark this block as reserved.

[image: CVE ID assignment process]

All CVE-20XX-1000XXX vulnerabilities were allocated by the [Distributed Weakness Filing Project](https://distributedweaknessfiling.org/), which is a root CNA, according to the [CNA list](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/request_id.html).

[As stated by MITRE](https://cve.mitre.org/news/archives/2016/news.html#august182016_DWF_CNA_Using_Seven_Digit_CVE_IDs), the DWF project were assigned a 7-digit block to differentiate their assignments from other CNA assignments, that's why there's such a large jump.